# Apigee OPTIONS 404

Tags: cross-domain, cors, apigee

I have been stumped by Apigee's CORS support. I setup a new proxy and made sure to tick the " Enable Direct Browser Access for Your API — Allow direct requests from a browser via CORS." box.

It appears that CORS is working for the normal GET requests, however pre-flight OPTIONS requests are not found and are returning a 404. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20058148/610982) but was not able to resolve my problem because it seems like a different problem perhaps?

The main question I would like answered is how do I setup Access-Control-Allow-Origin=* for all requests? Even OPTIONS requests?

Proxy Endpoints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
    <Description/>
    <Flows>
        <Flow name="Forecast">
            <Description/>
            <Request/>
            <Response/>
            <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath &quot;/forecast&quot;) and (request.verb = &quot;GET&quot;)</Condition>
        </Flow>
    </Flows>
    <PreFlow name="PreFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PreFlow>
    <HTTPProxyConnection>
        <BasePath>/v1/weather</BasePath>
        <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
    </HTTPProxyConnection>
    <RouteRule name="default">
        <TargetEndpoint>default</TargetEndpoint>
    </RouteRule>
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
</ProxyEndpoint>
```

Target Endpoints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TargetEndpoint name="default">
    <Description/>
    <Flows>
        <Flow name="OptionsCORS">
            <Description/>
            <Request/>
            <Response>
                <Step>
                    <Name>CrossOriginResourceSharing</Name>
                </Step>
            </Response>
            <Condition>request.verb equals "OPTIONS"</Condition>
        </Flow>
    </Flows>
    <PreFlow name="PreFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response>
            <Step>
                <Name>CrossOriginResourceSharing</Name>
            </Step>
        </Response>
    </PreFlow>
    <HTTPTargetConnection>
        <URL>https://home.nest.com/api/0.1/weather</URL>
    </HTTPTargetConnection>
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

Add CORS File

```
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="CrossOriginResourceSharing">
    <DisplayName>Add CORS</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Add>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin">*</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers">origin, x-requested-with, accept</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Max-Age">3628800</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods">GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS</Header>
        </Headers>
    </Add>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="response"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

Just in case it helps- the following is the error I get when doing my request. I'm using Chrome and have an AngularJS app. I've been able to replicate the issue using a cURL statement as well 
( curl -H "Origin: localhost" --verbose http://*********-prod.apigee.net/v1/weather/forecast/12345 -X OPTIONS )

```
{
    "url": "/api/0.1/weather/forecast/73013",
    "message": "404 Not Found"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a RouteRule that prevented the request from passing through to my API on OPTIONS requests.

```
<RouteRule name="NoRoute">
    <Condition>request.verb == "OPTIONS"</Condition>
</RouteRule>
```

Additionally I added a flow that added CORS support to the response

```
<Flow name="OptionsPreFlight">
    <Request/>
        <Response>
            <Step>
                <Name>Add-CORS</Name>
            </Step>
        </Response>
    <Condition>request.verb == "OPTIONS"</Condition>
</Flow>
```

And my Final Add-CORS policy

```
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Add-CORS">
    <DisplayName>Add CORS</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Add>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin">*</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers">origin, x-requested-with, accept</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Max-Age">3628800</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods">GET, PUT, POST, DELETE</Header>
        </Headers>
    </Add>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="response"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

Comment: There's a documentation in Apigee on CORS preflight request http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/adding-cors-support-api-proxy

Answer (score 2):

In your proxy.xml you add one more flow specific to OPTIONS

```
<Flow name="OPTIONS">
   <Description>This flow is for client side applications</Description>
      <Response>
         <Step>
            <Name>CORSResponse</Name>
         </Step>
      </Response>
   <Condition>(request.verb = &quot;OPTIONS&quot;)</Condition>
   <Request/>
</Flow>
```

Now the CORSResponse.xml Policy can be like below

```
<AssignMessage name="CORSResponse">
    <AssignTo type="response" createNew="true" />
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>

    <Set>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin">yourdomain.com</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers">origin, x-requested-with, x-source-ip, Accept, Authorization, User-Agent, Host, Accept-Language, Location, Referer</Header>
            <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods">GET, POST</Header>
        </Headers>
        <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
    </Set>

</AssignMessage>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response @santanu-dey. I took a step back and realized that the 404 I'm receiving is from my endpoint. My knowledge of CORS is still limited at this point so I'm wondering if I need to prevent the OPTIONS request from even going through to the endpoint and just returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin with StatusCode 200. Is that what _should_ be happening with the information you posted?

Comment: My understanding of CORS pre-flight is that the CORS preflight specifies what sort of cross-domain requests it is willing to handle. So that browsers / clients do not send unexpected / unsafe requests. It is like a protocol thing, has nothing to do with the actual service logic / content on the server side. Hence it is desirable to handle OPTIONS calls upfront in the apiproxy before entering into any other logic.

Comment: when I plug in your suggested code I receive this 405 response: {
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Received 405 Response without Allow Header",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "protocol.http.Response405WithoutAllowHeader"
        }
    }
}

Comment: That error is thrown by Apigee when your backend sends 405 response without an Alllow header (To comply with HTTP spec).  So possibly your OPTIONS call is traveling all the way through to your backend. Try attaching the policy in the request path itself to short circuit. Like  <Request>
         <Step>
            <Name>CORSResponse</Name>
         </Step>
      </Request>